# Hierachical cluster analysis of ordinal variables?

Tags: r, clustering, zero-inflation, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a dataset containing 400 variables (chemical compounds, amount classes) with values 0,1,2, or 3 and 50 entries (species).

Can I use hierarchical cluster analysis to get a dendrogram that shows similarities between different entries? There are a lot of 0's, about 80 % or more, in the dataset.

Which package in R you recommend? The one I tried uses only numerical variables.

Answer (score 1):

HAC needs a dissimilarity matrix.

Compute the matrix as required for your application, e g., using rank correlation.